# Basic usage of QAbstractTableModel::insertRows()

Tags: qt

I implemented QAbstractTableModel with the usual:

```
class PrintIntervalTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
private:
  virtual int rowCount (const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
  virtual int columnCount (const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
  virtual QVariant data (const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
  virtual QVariant headerData (int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
  virtual bool setData (const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::EditRole);
  virtual Qt::ItemFlags flags (const QModelIndex & index) const;

  virtual bool insertRows (int position, int rows, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex());
  virtual bool removeRows (int position, int rows, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex());
```

Here is my insert rows, which is pretty simple:

```
bool PrintIntervalTableModel::insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex & parent)
{
  beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), position, position + rows - 1);

  for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
  {
    std::deque<moment_value_pair_type>::iterator it = printIntervalPairs.begin() + position;
    printIntervalPairs.insert(it, moment_value_pair_type());
  }

  endInsertRows();

  return true;
}
```

Now I wonder why I actually did this? Do views (or other components) automatically call this method?

I would like to have a button on the form that, once clicked, inserts a row underneath the user's current selection. Do I basically create a slot in the table (connected to button clicked()) that figures out where to insert the row, and then the slot would call table->insertRows()? Is this the type of purpose the insertRows() override is used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late, but anyway:

> Now I wonder why I actually did this? Do views (or other components) automatically call this method?

Yes, `insertRows()` is called by the default implementation of `QAbstractItemModel::dropMimeData()`, which gets called when items from another Qt view are dropped there.

Likewise, `removeRows()` is called by the default implementation of `QAbstractItemView::startDrag()`.

I couldn't find other usages in the source.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I basically create a slot in the table (connected to button
>   clicked()) that figures out where to insert the row, and then the slot
>   would call table->insertRows()? Is this the type of purpose the
>   insertRows() override is used for?

Yes (Intented to be used by the view through QAbstractItemModel interface). 
You can look at the source code of QTableWidget as example.

```
void QTableWidget::insertRow(int row)
{
    Q_D(QTableWidget);
    d->tableModel()->insertRows(row);
}
```

You will notice (h file) insertRow here is a slot (to notify it typically by 
means of a selection model signal). It then calls insertRows (the 
function that you've overridden). A typical implementation can be found in the 
sources:

```
bool QTableModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &)
{
    if (count < 1 || row < 0 || row > verticalHeaderItems.count())
        return false;

    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row + count - 1);
    int rc = verticalHeaderItems.count();
    int cc = horizontalHeaderItems.count();
    verticalHeaderItems.insert(row, count, 0);
    if (rc == 0)
        tableItems.resize(cc * count);
    else
        tableItems.insert(tableIndex(row, 0), cc * count, 0);
    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}
```